# How best to Convert Nancy.HttpStatusCode to System.Net.Http.HeepStatusCode?

Tags: dotnet-httpclient, nancy

In our app we use Nancy, but also use HttpClient to do some work.  So we need to sometimes convert between the two types of status code.

Here is our solution:

```
var code = ((int)response.StatusCode).ToString();
var nancy_code = (Nancy.HttpStatusCode) Enum.Parse(typeof(Nancy.HttpStatusCode), code);
```

It seems really odd that there is not a simpler conversion.  Does anyone know what I may be missing here?